# Extracting from two Arrays with similar ids in a object

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I have two arrays with as follows :-

```
let locationList = [
    {
        id: "1",
        name: "Texas de Brazil",
        location: "Albany, NY"
    }
    {
        id: "2",
        name: "The Riverfront",
        location: "Troy NY"
    },
];

const eventList = [
    {
        id: "0",
        attendees: [1, 2],
        title: "Dinner at Texas de Brazil",
        startTime: new Date("1/15/2016"),
        description: "Going out to dinner to a fancy restaurant",
        location: 1
    },
    {
        id: "1",
        attendees: [1, 2, 3, 4],
        title: "Gala",
        startTime: new Date("2/07/2016"),
        description: "Have to attend a gala for fundraising with other very important people",
        location: 2
    },
    {
        id: "2",
        attendees: [1, 2, 4, 6],
        title: "End of Year Celebration",
        startTime: new Date("5/15/2016"),
        description: "Going out to dinner to a fancy restaurant, this time to celebrate end of school year",
        location: 1
    },
];
```

For the route location/:id,  I  want to extract all the details for the location and all the events from the  eventsList which will be taking place in that location for eg: for route "location/1", i want to return both name and location and from the eventList, all the  event that will be taking place in that location i.e 0 and 2. How can i return them. Currently, I am able to return just the details of the location using the following code

```
router.get("/:id", (req, res) => {
    locationData.getLocation(req.params.id).then((location) => {
        res.render("misc/location", {location: location});
    });
});
```

and this is my getLocation function :-

```
 getLocation: (id) => {
        if (id === undefined) return Promise.reject("No id provided");

        let location = locationList.filter(x => x.id === id).shift();
        if (!location) return Promise.reject("No location found")

        return Promise.resolve(location);
    }
```

P.S - I am not using mongoDB. These are just simple predefined arrays with objects inside them.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to check the event arrays. A simple filter like:

```
var locationId = 1;
var matchedEvents = eventList.filter(function(event){
  return event.location === locationId;
});
```

This will make a new array with all the matching items. A simple check of whether the location ids match.

Then, you will need to put that in the final result.

```
var result = null;
//...your code here
//now result is a location object
result.events = [];
//...push matchedEvents into the list
//Resolve the response
```